# RVM, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 2.3.8, Passenger and "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, rvm

I just started the upgrade process from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.2 (using RVM). I have all my applications running using 'script/server' (or 'rails server') with 1.9.2, however, only Rails 3.0.0 RC applications work with Passenger. The error message given by Rails 2.3.8 applications is:

> invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

I'm guessing that this is a Passenger issue. I installed Passenger 2.2.15 using the RVM guide found [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/). Any ideas how to fix this bug? Thanks. I've updated to include a stack trace:

```
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template_handlers/erb.rb:14:in `compile'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template_handler.rb:11:in `call'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:19:in `compiled_source'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:68:in `compile!'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:61:in `compile'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:28:in `render'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:352:in `_render_with_layout'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1250:in `render_for_file'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:942:in `render'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `block in render_with_benchmark'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `block in ms'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:135:in `block in custom'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:179:in `call'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:179:in `block in respond'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in `each'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in `respond'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:107:in `respond_to'
/Users/kevin/Sites/sample/app/controllers/main_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Comment: Any other information about the error? Where does it happen? Stack trace perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

at the top of your main_controller.rb file. If that works, you're dealing with a non US ASCII character in your source file.

In Ruby 1.9, we're dealing with three encoding contexts:

- Source code encoding: Strings in a source file are interpreted as US-ASCII by default, unless the magic comment I list above is present.
- External encoding: The characters in a text file are assumed to be in the same encoding as the environment. However one can specify the encoding to use. Eg: open(mydata.txt, "r:UTF-8").
- Internal encoding: That specifies how the text data is encoded once read from a file. By default this is nil, meaning it will be the same as the encoding used to read it. If something different is needed, it can be specified in IO.open. Eg: open(mydata.txt, 'r:UTF-8:UTF-16LE')

For more info, I'd read [James Edward Gray II's great articles](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) on encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any non US ASCII characters in the source files. I think it must be a passenger issue (given that the projects all run fine under mongrel).

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues on Ubuntu (11.10) because this was in my /etc/apache2/envvars:

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale
```

Swapping the comments out on this one to use the /etc/default/locale (which contains `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`) resolved the issue for me without having to make a wrapper for my ruby.

Comment: This answer worked for me on ubuntu 12.04 with a rails 3.2 app running in ruby 1.9.3. There were UTF-8-encoded characters in the gemspecs for some of the gems in use in the app.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with a different server, and [environment variables turned out to be the culprit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597255/why-does-my-sproutcore-development-server-drop-connections-with-invalid-byte-seq/3598303#3598303).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with pjmorse regarding the environment variable cause, specially in my Passenger/Rails set-up, the culprit was the LANG value.

When starting my Rails app through script/server, I had LANG=en_CA.UTF-8, but not when raising the app with Passenger.

Solution:
Modify the Passenger configuration to start Ruby with a wrapper, see http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/12/16/passing-environment-variables-to-ruby-from-phusion-passenger/

Use this as a wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
exec "/Your_Default_Ruby_Path/ruby" "$@"
```

Note Your_Default_Ruby_Path is whatever was in the PassengerRuby value of the http.conf before you set-up the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of forced string encoding; the error is a Ruby 1.9.x vs Ruby 1.8.x behavior difference in strings.

Check http://blog.phusion.nl/2009/02/02/getting-ready-for-ruby-191/ -- might be helpful. You probably just need to update your gemset.

Comment: Is this a problem with the passenger gem then? The applications appear to run fine using the built in Mongreal (script/server). Also it doesn't seem to explain why 3.0.0 RC applications are working. Any ideas?