# Why does my Sproutcore development server drop connections with "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Here's the stack: Sproutcore 1.0.1046. Ruby 1.9.1, in RVM. Thin 1.2.7. Thor 0.13.8. Rack 1.2.1. Eventmachine 0.12.10. Erubis 2.6.6.

When I start the `sc-server` on any application, my first request to this server produces this in the console log:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

...followed by [this stack trace](http://gist.github.com/532793). (I've listed gems which appear in the stack trace above, but there's a complete gemset list in the same gist as the stack trace.)

Research on the error message points out that this is a common problem with Ruby 1.9, but the stack trace suggests that the problem is in one of the gems somewhere.

I have:

- Upgraded my OS (Mac OS X 10.5 to 10.6) in order to get the latest `gcc` Apple provides.
- Reinstalled RVM.
- Reinstalled Ruby.
- Reinstalled all the relevant gems.

And yet I still have this problem on one system, but not on another. (N.B. there are several devs working on this code, and I'm the only one seeing this problem. I'm 99% certain it's not our code.) I guess what I'm saying is that I've cleared and rebuilt a lot of gems to try to isolate or remove this glitch, and yet I still haven't gotten rid of it.

Where should I look next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some special setting in your bash environment that is setting ruby to use US-ASCII , this happened to me trying to execute sc-server from a remote terminal... I'm not really sure what it is, but it doesn't use UTF-8 and that's when it runs into trouble.

Comment: You can see what's in your environment variables by running the 'env' command from bash.  Or by examining the ENV hash in Ruby.

Comment: THANK YOU. I checked the environments on the two systems, and the one that worked had several `en_US.UTF-8` settings, and the one that didn't has several `en_US.us-ascii` settings. The LC_CTYPE environment variable seems to be the key, because setting that in my .bash_profile seemed to solve the problem without changing any others.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably also change Encoding.default_external

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for the Encoding.default_external suggestion. I was having the same problem, despite correctly set magic comments and environment variables. In Rails 2.3.9 I added this before_filter in application_controller.rb, resolved the issue:

```
def set_encoding
  Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'
end
```

Comment: This fixed problems in my Mac OS X Lion dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with RSS Feeds that I was displaying in a Rails 2.3.8 app with Ruby 1.9.2. My issue wasn't solved by the application_controller.rb before_filter technique mentioned here. The fix was to put the following into "RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/string_encodings.rb":

> Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'

That worked for me site-wide, instead of on a controller level.

Comment: I'm sure that would work for a Rails app, but the one I was having this problem with wasn't a Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the ArgumentError occurred during a Capistrano deploy call that envolves ruby's net-ssh (ruby 1.9.2p290, net-ssh 2.3.0). None of the solutions afore mentioned worked and none of the other reasons I've read about so far: i.e. "strange character in key file", etc..

Finally, I found a none ASCII-character in a comment(!) line in my ASCII encoded ~/.ssh/config file. BINGO!