# How to deal with invalid byte sequence for user input via Rack middleware?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, user-input, rack

So some of the users in our system are copying and pasting text into my app. In my logs I will occasionally notice this:

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:68:in `=~'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:68:in `!~'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:68:in `blank?'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/response.rb:202:in `nonempty_ok_response?'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/response.rb:188:in `handle_conditional_get!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/response.rb:141:in `prepare!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:540:in `send_response'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:534:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
```

And here are the request details. Notice the invalid characters.

```
Parameters: {"attendee"=>{"segment"=>"Middle Market \xE2\x80\x93 West Region"}}
```

The problem is that the character encodings are off. My application is setup for UTF-8, and I believe they are sending ASCII characters. I need a way to filter this so that I can avoid the above error.

Notice that the error is being raised before it even gets to my application. Therefore, I'm assuming the best solution is Rack middleware that filters user input to ensure its the proper encoding.

Any idea on the best way to accomplish this? I'm 100% fine if invalid characters get replaced with a question mark. Or a response is sent back saying your input has invalid characters. Right now they are just getting a generic error, and on ajax requests they get nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: "My application is setup for UTF-8, and I believe they are sending ASCII characters." If they are sending "ASCII characters", they are also sending "UTF-8 characters". Any ASCII bytestring is a valid UTF-8 bytestring.

Answer (score 0):

See [RVM, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 2.3.8, Passenger and "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515810/rvm-ruby-1-9-2-rails-2-3-8-passenger-and-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii) and https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3941-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-error-for-utf-8-localized-messages.

Basically you need to add

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

to your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your views have a line like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Any browser will send form data encoded as specified by the HTML's charset. So it doesn't matter where users are copy-pasting data from, the browser will take care of converting the data to UTF8 on post.

Comment: Yep, I have that exact meta tag. My guess is that Microsoft decided not to honor it. But that meta tag is on every one of my pages. And it would be awesome if it was that simple.